# EF TPT generating duplicate foreign keys

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am writing an application which uses inheritance and I'm trying to map this to a SQL Server database with TPT structure.

However, for some reason EF generates duplicate foreign keys in both the superclass and subclass tables.

I have these classes:

```
public abstract class Answer
{
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage = "The answer cannot contain more than 250 characters")]
    public String Text { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(1500, ErrorMessage = "The description cannot contain more than 1500 characters")]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class AgendaAnswer : Answer
{
    [Required]
    public AgendaModule AgendaModule { get; set; }
}

public class SolutionAnswer : Answer
{
    [Required]
    public SolutionModule SolutionModule { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Module
{
    // for some reason EF doesn't recognize this as primary key
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Question { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class AgendaModule : Module
{
    public IList<AgendaAnswer> AgendaAnswers { get; set; }
}

public class SolutionModule : Module
{
    public IList<SolutionAnswer> SolutionAnswers { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public int Zip { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<AgendaAnswer> AgendaAnswers { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<SolutionAnswer> SolutionAnswers { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the content of my DbContext class:

```
public DbSet<AgendaModule> AgendaModules { get; set; }
public DbSet<SolutionModule> SolutionModules { get; set; }
public DbSet<AgendaAnswer> AgendaAnswers { get; set; }
public DbSet<SolutionAnswer> SolutionAnswers { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Module>().HasKey(m => m.ModuleId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>().HasKey(a => a.AnswerId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<AgendaAnswer>().Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("AgendaAnswers");
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<SolutionAnswer>().Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("SolutionAnswers");
    });
}
```

When I run my application, EF creates the tables how I want them (TPT), but it duplicates the foreign key to users in each of them (see picture).

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to remove the AgendaAnswers and SolutionAnswers properties from the User class.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem.
I wonder though if there's a way to keep the two subclass collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comment above, the solution is to remove the `AgendaAnswers` and `SolutionAnswers` properties from the User class.

If you want to keep those collections in the `User` class, you might have to remove the `User` and `UserId` properties from the `Answer` class and instead duplicate them in the `AgendaAnswer` and `SolutionAnswer` classes. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619452/entity-framework-fluent-api-does-not-consider-base-class-properties) for more information.